# Conditional inclusion of <script> tags with jsdom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsdom

I'm trying to modify a local HTML file by including  tags for a local .js file and 2.0.3 jquery.min.js. Here is an excerpt from the code (entire script is [here](http://fpaste.org/37566/)):

```
 jsdom.env(
  data,
  ["//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js", "../javascripts/fixit.js"],
  function (errors, window) {
    var $ = window.jQuery;
⋮
```

Now, if I run the script twice, it includes both of these links in the HTML again. Is there a way to make this conditional and include the  tags only if they are not already present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I maintain jsdom.)

The whole point of jsdom is you can do normal DOM operations, like testing for an element's presence or inserting an element, inside Node. So I would do something like this:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;

var document = jsdom(data);

if (!document.head.querySelector("script[src$='2.0.3/jquery.min.js']")) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}

// Same for ../javascripts/fixit.js
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: is it possible to access the `window` object of jsdom(data) from outside, or only in the callback function?

Comment: `document.parentWindow` is the standard DOM API you're looking for.

Comment: So `if(typeof document.parentWindow.jQuery ==  "undefined")` could work as well, right?

Comment: Not until after the script loads; you'd need to attach a handler to the `load` event and check there. (Or use `jsdom.env`, which will only call back when everything is loaded.)

Comment: Sorry for a noob question but what is the dollar sign for after "src" in the query selector?

Comment: Is there any way to pass the `document` variable to `jsdom.env` so that I can use jQuery for the `.append` and `.each` calls?

Comment: @mart1n just like in the browser, `window.document` will work great.

Comment: I must be too stupid for this :( Any ideas why this won't work: http://fpaste.org/38389/ ? It's like the entire jQuerify callback is ignored.

Comment: You should probably check the error parameter, passed as the first parameter to your callback. You're currently ignoring it. Also note that code inside the jQuerify callback runs later than code after it, since it's asynchronous, so the `console.log` after it won't show any changes from inside the jQuerify callback.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you with this. But, I just can't get it to work. It seems that the `window.$(config.elements.join(",")).each(function(index, value){...})` call is not being process. The index returns a 0 and any code after this call is ignored. This is the code I'm trying now: http://fpaste.org/38508/ . Could it possible be a bug? No errors are thrown btw.

Answer (score 2):

[Edit: **it's wrong**. See edit below].
Check if jQuery is already defined, include scripts if not.

```
var scripts = [], undef;
if(typeof window.jQuery === typeof undef){
    scripts = ["//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js", "../javascripts/fixit.js"];
}

jsdom.env(
  data,
  scripts,
  function (errors, window) {
⋮
```

I haven't tested it, but judging by jsdom [source code](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/lib/jsdom.js#L268) it'll fire scriptComplete callback if `config.scripts` is an empty array.

**EDIT**: after reading your comments I've realized it's not going to work. The context in which I check for `jQuery` is outside of the scope of `jsdom.env`'s `window` object. And jsdom doesn't check for the existence of scripts you want to append as its use case is probably in-memory operations on temporary DOM.

So if you need to persist the modified DOM and be able to re-read it from file and process again without adding these duplicate `<scipt />` elements the easiest solution would be to get rid of them just before writing the file.

```
/* if you don't want to save the document with <script> elements at all */
Array.prototype.slice.call( document.scripts ) // convert document.scripts to regular Array
.forEach( 
    function( script ){ 
      /* you probably want to check if script.src matches jQuery or whatever,
       * e.g. if( script.src.indexOf('jquery.min.js' > -1 ){
       */
       script.parentNode.removeChild( script ); 
 });


/* alternatively if you want to have each <script> exactly one (remove duplicates) */
var srcs = {};
Array.prototype.slice.call( document.scripts ) // convert document.scripts to regular Array
  .forEach( 
     function( script ){ 
        if( srcs[ scipt.src ] ){
           script.parentNode.removeChild( script );
        }
        else {
           srcs[ script.src ] = 1;
        }
  });
```

Add one of the above before this line:

```
var output = window.document.doctype + window.document.innerHTML;
```

By the way `$("head").append('<link ...` in your code will add this link multiple times as well. You should check for its existence:

```
if( $('link[src$="stylesheets/test.css"]').length == 0 ) $("head").append('<link ...
```

Comment: Great solution. But it complains that `window` is not defined: `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Edit: probably because we only define it in the callback for `jsdom.env`.

Comment: Also, checking for the globalFromFixit variable doesn't work as it probably doesn't load the scripts up until the callback in `jsdom.env` is fired. I guess I could just search for the string in `data` but that seems like an expensive operation.